# Travis CI Build Failure

Tags: java, gradle, travis-ci, gradlew

I'm attempting to get a Travis CI build to work.  The build was fine until I configured the `gradle.build` file to upload to Maven Central.  I don't want to configure the Travis CI build to actually upload releases yet. I just want it to verify the build, and run tests.

My original `.travis.yml` file stopped working because of the `./gradlew assemble` task runs signArchives has properties that I hadn't defined.  I now fixed the script to define these properties, but it fails at the signArchives task since I don't have this setup on Travis CI.

I tried to [customize the build step](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Customizing-the-Build-Step) using the following script, but it still ends up running `./gradlew assemble`.

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
script: gradle build -x signArchives
```

Why is it not honoring my custom defined script?

[GitHub project](https://github.com/GreaterMKEMeetup/slack-integrations-api)

[Failed Travis CI Build](https://travis-ci.org/GreaterMKEMeetup/slack-integrations-api/builds/147529347)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Per the suggestion of @travisci](https://twitter.com/travisci/status/757995641238876160) (thanks for the quick help!), I changed the `script:` step to `install:`.

```yml
language: java

jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

install:
  - ./gradlew assemble -x signArchives
```